# Random points with minimum distance [Octave]

Tags: matlab, octave, distribution

I'm trying to generate a cube with `n` random points all with a minimum distance threshold of `1`. I'm using a matrix to do it in so each column would be `(x,y,z)` points in the cube. I have the code sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work. I really can't figure out why that is though...any help or advice is appreciated the input of the code is the length of one of the sides of the cube and the number of points I want to use.

Updates:
Clarification on code:
So it is supposed to create a random matrix with `3` columns and `n` rows. This represents the `(x,y,z)` coordinates for `n` points in a cube. The constraints are the size of the cube `lx` and the minimum distance between the points `d`. So my code generates a `nx3` random matrix and checks each entry to see if their distance is at least `1`, if it isn't it generates a new point for that element. Then it goes back and checks all the previous points to keep that restriction. It's failing because some points have a distance less than `1`. I don't know if I'm not doing enough checks or if it's something else.

Input values:

- length of the cube: `lx = 7.35`
- number of points: `n = 256`

Code:

```
    function [A]=distribution(lx,n)
    format long;
    A=0;
    new=0;
    d=1;
    A=rand(n,3).* [lx];
    A=reshape( A.' ,3,n);
    while(new <= (n+1))
    for i=1:(n-1)
        for j=(i+1):n
            r=A(:,i) - A(:,j);
            rsum= sum(dot(r,r));
            if(rsum < 1.0)
                A(:,j)=rand(1,3).* [lx];
            end
        end
        for k=1:i-1
            r2=A(:,k) - A(:,i);
            r2sum= sum(dot(r2,r2));
            if(r2sum < 1.0)
                A(:,j)=rand(3,1).* [lx];
            end
        end
    end
    new=new +1;
    endwhile
    A=reshape( A.' ,n,[]);
```

Comment: "sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work" is pretty vague. What is your code supposed to do and how exactly does it fail to do that?

Comment: So it is supposed to create a random matrix with 3 columns and N rows. This represents a XYZ coordinate for points in a cube. The constraints are the size of the cube (lx) and the minimum distance between the points (d). So my code generates a nx3 random matrix and checks each entry to see if their distance is at least 1, if it isn't it generates a new point for that element. Then it goes back and checks all the previous points to keep that restriction. Its failing because some points have  a distance less than 1.

Comment: It's a random process, so I would expect it to fail sometimes. What values are you passing as input? Please add any updates or clarification (including your previous comment) to the original question by clicking [edit].

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even though it is a random process, I don't think it should fail at all because in the code it is supposed to check all the points against each other. If the point is faulty it should replace it with a new one and recheck all the points again.I don't know if I'm not doing enough checks or if it's something else.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your algorithm. It looks like, for each point, you compare it to every other point. If the distance is below the threshold, you move the point. Then check the next. If the distance is too small, move it again, but you don't check the previously checked points with the new position(s) until the next big loop. The outer `while` loop seems to be equivalent to a `for` loop over `0:n+1`. Is that pretty much it?

Comment: Your code works for smaller numbers of points, so I guess it does what you intended. Without getting into some wild algorithms, I guess you need to perform more iterations. One thing I'd suggest is that you keep track of whether or not a point was moved on an iteration. If not, you can stop.

Comment: Yea that's pretty much it you got it. I increased the number of iterations from n+1 to 2*n and that seems to have worked out for the trials I've run so far. Thanks for your help. I'll try to work on that second part of keeping track

Answer (score 0):

How random do the points need to be? Even though there are possible solutions, they are few compared to all possible states. Hitting a solution totally at random may take indefinitely long.

I can suggest couple of approaches:

1. Set the points in a grid, and then randomize them to some extend. If you apply the randomization of the coordinates on point-by-point basis, you can "undo" the change if it causes some distance to fall under 1.
2. Start with an "initial" point at the center of the allowed space and add layers of points, by the means of polar coordinates with random angles and radius 1 from the "initial" point. Once you add a layer, you can just increase the radius to 2 and keep the "initial" point as origin. Alternatively, loop over the points of the last added layer, and try to add new ones in a similar way. The distance have to be checked against all earlier points in either case.

In both approaches, the final result will not be quite random. The way I see it, to get the truly random solution, you need to make a stochastic physical simulation of 256 balls in a box with side `lx` and jiggle them a bit.

Comment: That's a good quesiton...I'm not exactly sure how random it's supposed to be. 

You are exactly right in it takes a rather long time to run. By decreasing the box size and keeping the particles the same it's almost an exponential increase in time taken. I was thinking I really need to figure out a way to optimize this code to make it more efficient.

I will definitely look at and try to implement your approach though.

Answer (score 0):

This problem in 2D is called Poisson disk distribution, and in 3D poisson sphere distribution. THere are known reasonable good solutions to this problem, check [paper](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~ares.lagae/publications/LD06PSD/LD06PSD.pdf).

Supposedly working code in Matlab [here](http://cusacklabcomputing.blogspot.com/2013/07/poisson-disc-2d-in-matlab.html), if it doesn't work I might dig out my Python implementation

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried the 3D version of this code and would get inconsistent matrix sizes. Instead of 256 X 3 matrix I would get a 200, 207,216 x 3 matrix and couldn't figure out why it was doing that.